# How to get all existing classes with specified class name (or by inheritance) dynamically?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, unity-game-engine

For example I made parent class CFilter and then I made some child classes with similar class names, for example CFilterNoise, CFilterLines, CFilterFillColor.
I don't now how many classes I will make in future, but i want to create one instance for every class with CFilter* name, or all childs of CFilter in FOR or WHILE loop once at start.
How can I do that?

Comment: You're looking for Reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can look in your assemblies to find all class that inherit CFilter :

```
foreach (Assembly a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())// get all assemblies
{
    foreach (Type t in a.GetTypes()) // get all types in the assembly
    {
        if( t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(CFilter) ) )// if the type inherit CFilter
        {
           var instance = (CFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(t);// create an instance ( with the default constructor ) of the type
           // use 'instance'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it now. And write some later if something go wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to automatically create one of each class based on its name. But you can check if a class implements the interface you want. You can even write it as an extension method.

```
bool IsAFilter<T>(this T myobject)
{
    return (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CFilter))
}
```

Using IsAssignableFrom will tell you if the class you have implements CFilter.

Comment: Thats good idea. But using this I can only check is class child of specified class. I want to get all classes of specified and create 1 instance of them.